# Windows 8 class library marshalled for a different thread

Tags: windows-8

From  the Windows 8 Class library if I am trying to update my UI, I get this error:
`The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.` I am unable to resolve the problem since `Dispatcher.RunAsync` method is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not good way to update UI from other threads.

Why Dispacher.RunAsync is not available?

```
this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
  YourMethod();
});
```

or try to use as await task:

```
this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
  YourMethod()();
}).AsTask().Wait();

**this** is reference to **Window.Current**.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it resolved my issue. in my class library code "this" was referred to Window.Current. when i resolve the reference for "Dispatcher" it referred to "System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher" instead of "Window.Current.Dispatcher"